# Есть ли плагин для Gulp, который будет компилировать scss в css с прописанием стилей для всех браузеров(типо koala)?

Tags: css, gulp, npm, scss

```
// scss
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

// css.min
div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, вы ищите что-то наподобие [gulp-autoprefixer](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-autoprefixer#readme).

Пример:
1)В package.json нужно иметь секцию browserslist, например такую

```
"browserslist": [
    "last 5 version",
    "Firefox ESR",
    ">5%"
],
```

Содержимое можно взять/уточнить покрытие на https://browsersl.ist/

---

2)простейший gulpfile.js

```
var postcss = require("gulp-postcss");
var gulp = require("gulp");
var autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
var cssnano = require("cssnano");

gulp.task("sass", function () {
var plugins = [autoprefixer(), cssnano()];
return gulp
    .src("src/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(postcss(plugins))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dest/css"));
});

gulp.task("default", gulp.series("sass"));
```

Comment: Я пока ещё не на "ты" c Gulp. Покопался в настройках overrideBrowserlist, поправил, теперь всё работает.
Спасибо,что помог разобраться.